# Create dynamic input and store values on object with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

What I trying to do is, generate dynamic `input` and collect all values into an `object` with dynamic name, so I defined an empty `object` in state:

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            setting_value: {}, // our object
            setting_append: 0, // define how input will be append
        };
    }
```

Then I append first `input` as default input:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.handleAppend(); // run this on load
}
```

In this function I append an `input` then create an `item` and add to current object:

```
handleAppend = () => {
    this.setState({
        setting_append: this.state.setting_append + 1
    });
    let name = '';
    let obj = this.state.setting_value; // current object
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.setting_append; i++){
        name = 'input_' + i;
        obj[name] = null;
    }
    this.setState({
        setting_value: obj
    })
}
```

And render like this:

```
render() {
const InputList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.setting_append; i++) {
    InputList.push(i);
}
...

return (
{InputList && InputList.map(function (El, Index) {
    return (
        <Col key={Index} md="6">
            <Label>input {Index}</Label>
            <Input onChange={(e) => {this.handleValues(e, Index)}}/>
        </Col>
    )
})}
)
<Button onClick={this.handleAppend}>+</Button> // append more input
```

And this is our change function:

```
handleValues = (e, row) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let input_name = 'input_' + row;
    if(value){
        const new_obj = {...this.state.setting_value, ...{ [input_name]: value}}
        this.setState({
            setting_value: new_obj
        });
        console.log(new_obj);
    }

}
```

**Problem!**

Okay, after page load, I got one input, then I type some text and output is *(log)*:

```
{input_0: 'xxxx'}
```

Then I click on button to append another input, then type some text:

```
{input_0: null, input_1: '12'}
```

it make previous input `null` but I need this output:

```
{input_0: 'xxxx', input_1: '12'}
```

Then if I type some new value on first input, output is:

```
{input_0: 'sdf'}
```

But should be:

```
{input_0: 'sdf', input_1: '12'}
```

Any idea what I have done wrong?

Comment: Because you set each object to `null`  here-> `obj[name] = null` everytime you `handleAppend` !

Comment: @Pedram I want to set new item value to null, not previous

Comment: So name it like this `name = 'input_' + this.state.setting_append;` not with `i`, because it repeat from zero everytime!